# Oracle RAC One Node

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

In the latest version of Oracle Database (11g Release 2), there's a new option called Real Application Clusters (RAC) One Node. What is "One Node", and how does it differ from regular RAC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mogens Norgaard](http://wedonotuse.blogspot.com/) used to joke about "single node RAC" but now it actually exists!

Basically, One Node is running a RAC database on a single server, rather than across a cluster of servers.  There is an Oracle white paper on the topic.  [Find it here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/clustering/overview/twp-rac1nodev1-1-130698.pdf)  The money quote is:

*"Oracle RAC One Node enables:

• Better server consolidation

• Enhanced protection from failures

• Greater flexibility and workload management

• Better online maintenance

In addition it allows customers to virtualize database storage, standardize their database
environment, and, should the need arise, upgrade to a full multi-node Oracle RAC
database without downtime or disruption."*

Comment: Sadly, it is an extra-paid option to the (already expensive) Enterprise Edition.