# setting up an Oracle RAC test env. on a single machine

Tags: database, oracle11g

Is it possible to setup an Oracle RAC test environment on a single machine without using VMware or anything like that?

Comment: Oracle RAC One Node - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969218/oracle-rac-one-node/3969309#3969309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  Tim Hall has an article on setting up a [11g RAC cluster on a single server using multiple VMs](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/OracleDB11gR1RACInstallationOnOEL5UsingVMware.php) on his site.